# LSCOLORS and CLICOLOR active by default and unset

Tags: terminal, zsh

Running zsh out of the box `ls -G` produced a colored list with the default colored values. But when I `echo`, both `$LSCOLORS` and `$CLICOLOR`, I receive an empty response. Reviewing `printenv` or `set` also do not show these variables.

Unlike other questions asking how to change `LSCOLORS` and `CLICOLOR`, I want to ask where are the default options set, even though these environment variables are not set (in a way I can find)? Is there a way to view the background process, of `ls` for example, within terminal to trace these back to an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual page for `ls(1)` documents the defaults:

> The default is "exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad", i.e. blue foreground and default background for regular directories, black foreground and red background for setuid executables, etc.

Those defaults are compiled into the `ls` binary - you can confirm this by [browsing the source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-272.220.1/ls/). Note this definition in [print.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-272.220.1/ls/print.c.auto.html):

```
static const char *defcolors = "exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad";
```